# What's better about red eggs?

Tags: yoshis-island

I was watching a tool-assisted [speedrun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIpEGrNIc7s&t=0m56s) of Super Mario World 2: Yoshi's Island and I noticed that the players spend a lot of time turning green eggs yellow or red. What advantage do red or yellow eggs have over the green ones?

Comment: A fellow redditor I presume?

Comment: @Andy - Actually, my brother's the redditor: he showed it to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a red coin is collected with a red egg, two stars are given to Yoshi;  with a yellow, a coin.
They needed 30 stars, so they made red eggs to pick up a few on the way.

Comment: Are there any other differences, such as number of bounces, etc?

Comment: I don't think so.  (I only actually know this because I asked on the comments thread of the youtube video.  I haven't played the game in ages)